# How to interpret rotation_difference when objects are rotated?

Tags: vector

I'm having trouble interpreting the output of rotation_difference.

It works fine when the objects are not rotated in world space (as in, flat), but as soon as I rotate the two together, you'd think their rotation difference would be the same, yet the values change.

Here it shows the correct value, "Right", when the objects are not rotated in world space:
[image]
But when I rotate them together, like this, the output of rotation_difference is different, giving the "error":
[image]

In both pictures, A -> B is 90 degrees to the right of the plane (in object space.)

I'm sure there's nothing going wrong, but I would like to know if there's some better way to decode rotation_difference so it works no matter how the two objects are rotated in world space.

In the first picture, rotation_difference outputs:

```
<Quaternion (w=0.7071, x=0.0000, y=-0.0000, z=0.7071)>
```

and in the second picture it outputs:

```
<Quaternion (w=0.7071, x=-0.4867, y=0.4148, z=0.3018)>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems there's a way to achieve what I'm trying to do, but it does require that the object has its own local transformations; i.e. this will break if you rotate the object and `Ctrl` `A` --> `Apply Transforms`.

Nonetheless, here is the relevant code I used:

```
obj = bpy.data.objects['Cube']
cur = bpy.data.objects['Vert']

face = 1
normal_OBJ = obj.data.polygons[face].normal.to_4d()
normal_OBJ.w = 0
nw = (obj.matrix_world @ normal_OBJ).to_3d()
    
normalCUR = (cur.data.vertices[b].co) - (cur.data.vertices[a].co)
normal_CUR = normal.normalized().to_4d()
normal_CUR.w = 0
nwCur = (mwCur @ normalCur_local).to_3d()

rd = nwCur.rotation_difference(nw)

angle = round(math.degrees(rd.angle), 4)

# This is the important bit:
axis = rd.axis @ mwMol
```

And `print(axis)` and `print(angle)` should now output the same values no matter how the two objects are rotated together.